# How do I remove ugly google chrome icon in the Gnome3 applications tab?

Tags: gnome, icons, google-chrome

When I search in applications of Gnome for **Chrome**, I get two entries: the left one in the picture is OK with a high resolution icon, the right one has a low resolution icon.

I couldn't figure out where the second one is coming from. Does anyone have an idea?

I would like to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the second icon comes from the `google-chrome.desktop` file in `.local/share/applications`.

I would suggest you remove the file and retry again.

Answer (score 1):

Install alacarte to manually edit gnome menus. You can uncheck that icon and it wont show up again

Comment: @tijybba But it works.... :-)