# How to remove duplicate application in /usr/share/applications folder?

Tags: directory

I just started using XFCE and I'm loving it so far but I've yet to figure this out.

I'm having trouble removing a duplicate Google Chrome file in this folder. The main thing is I want to remove it from my menu since I have one under the Internet sub-folder in the menu and also one under Other. I'm OCD so this is driving me insane.

In the applications folder, the only thing that differentiates the two is that the duplicate just has the command entry (as "google-chrome" filled under properties while the other has a description and comment which is the one I want to keep.

I don't know how to remove the duplicate since the `rm` command says it can't find that directory (and I'm not sure how to word it exactly since they are both named the same).

I tried the fix of the "NoDisplay=true" but I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two since they both have the same name.

I also tried changing the duplicate to renaming it to the desktop.old extension but it said that it doesn't exist.

I'm ok with uninstalling and installing again if I can be absolutely sure it removes both.

---

**Edit:** Sorry for the late response and thanks for those who responded. I should have clarified better, I'm currently using the crouton installation of ubuntu on an Acer C720. I have just removed Google Chrome but this second application in the /usr/share/applications folder is still there, although its grey and doesn't launch anything since it's uninstalled. I tried this way (How to remove single file from /usr directory?) by using the command BUT, the file name is Google Chrome (and I've tried google-chrome, google-chrome.desktop) and I can't remove it by command because it doesn't recognize the space, so it looks for Google and Chrome separately and it says No such file or directory for both (including google-chrome and google-chrome.desktop). Anyone have any ideas of getting rid of this thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "I just started using XFCE"? Do you have a pure Xubuntu installation? Or have you added Xfce to an existing installation of something else? What exactly is your OS? How did you install XFCE?

Comment: This already has an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/178939/178596)...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second Google Chrome in the Internet menu of [Main Menu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/)
[image: package]
:
[image: Alacarte]

You may also have to remove the second one in the <kbd>Other</kbd> Category as well...