# How to remove duplicate (different version) application?

Tags: vlc, software-uninstall

I'm on 16.04 , and recently installed VLC 3.x . The problem is that this install did not remove an older 2.x version.  They both show up in the "Search your computer" tool, but they do not both appear in the UbuntuSoftwareManagement tool.

I did verify that the two icons which appear lead to the separate versions of VLC - this is not a duplicate of [duplicate icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178939/how-do-i-remove-ugly-google-chrome-icon-in-the-gnome3-applications-tab).

### edit:

yes, one is from snap and one isn't.  But that doesn't help, since I don't see how to specify which one I want to delete.  Further, I am not sure which (old or new) version "belongs" to snap in the first place.

Is there a gui-based app that will find duplicates like this and let me uninstall the older version, or do I have to track down the actual file locations and manually remove them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "vlc" and "VLC media player" in Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985564/what-is-the-difference-between-vlc-and-vlc-media-player-in-ubuntu-software-i) and https://askubuntu.com/q/972411. The advanced version is most likely the snap one, you can check by running `snap list`. You can remove it by running `snap remove vlc`.

Comment: @pomsky Thanks!  Naturally, snap was the newer version, so I went back and ran `sudo apt-get remove vlc` to dump the old version.